# Центрирование меню на ul-li

Tags: css, html, вёрстка

Добрый вечер. Проблема такая. Есть меню на ul-li, пунктов в ней на две строки, примерно так

```
Menu1  Menu2  Menu3  Menu4
Menu5  Menu6
```

Но требуется что-бы пункты были по центру, например вот так

```
Menu1 Menu2 Menu3 Menu4
     Menu5  Menu6
```

Использовать span вместо ul-li,возможно нет. Прошу подсказать, каким способом можно это сделать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Сделать li строчными и выровнять их по центру как текст:
http://jsfiddle.net/tc9bR/1/

Comment: Если нужны дополнительные комментарии по поводу строчности (inline), блочности (block) и "среднего" (inline-block), спрашивайте :)

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. Не знаю сколько бы еще над этим сидел. Спасибо.